# Qt Camera control could I use it on all cameras?

Tags: macos, qt, camera, qt5

I want to use QCamera class (for controlling a camera) in my application but this application needs to be used on the newest cameras in the shops. My application will be written in MAC OSX system for desktop but the application will be ported to other systems in future.

I need to know if I can use QCamera class and Qt as a whole for controlling "any" camera (exclude without USB support), or this is useful only for common webcameras on PC. I'm speaking mainly of Canon and Nickon manufacturers (these are required).

Best option will be if someone can get a list of supported devices if something like that exists.

Comment: Qt is using the operating system multimedia APIs to obtain the list of cameras, to get the video data, etc. If your camera is supported by the OS directly, it will work. If it requires custom software, then in won't work with anything but said custom software.

Comment: So when I need newest Canon and Nickon cameras. Are this supported by system, or their drivers are custom software?

Comment: Only you can answer that question. Attach the camera, run some 3rd party software, and check it out.